# Filtrar registros de resultados

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, sql, subconsultas, collection

Tengo un modelo Trabajador y un modelo Contrato. Dado un trabajador quiero retornar el contrato que esté activo a una fecha dada. Para ello miro que la fecha de inicio del contrato sea anterior a la fecha indicada y que la fecha final no exista o sea después de la fecha indicada.
Estoy trabajando en Laravel 6.0.
El error que recibo es:

```
explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

Os dejo el código del modelo Trabajador

```
class Trabajador extends Model
{
  public function contratos(){
    return $this->hasMany(Contrato::class);
  }

  public function contratoActivo($fecha){
    return $this->contratos->where('inicioContrato','<=',$fecha)
        ->where(function($query) use($fecha){
            $query->where('finContrato',null)
                ->orWhere('finContrato','>=',$fecha);
        });
  }
```

Comment: En PHP `explode()` devuelve un *array de strings* a partir de un *string*, entonces espera recibir un *string*, de otro modo fallará. Creo que tu problema es `$fecha`, haz un **debug**, con `dd()` por ejemplo, para comprobar que es un string y no un objeto.

Comment: Sí, `$fecha` es un string, incluso he probado a poner la fecha escrita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser que para hacer este tipo de consultas, en las relaciones, se ha de poner un paréntesis, para que haga la búsqueda en la base de datos en lugar de devolver la colección de objetos.

```
public function contratoActivo($fecha){
    return $this->contratos()->where('inicioContrato','<=',$fecha)
        ->where(function($query) use($fecha){
            $query->where('finContrato',null)
                ->orWhere('finContrato','>=',$fecha);
        });
  }
```

Dejo enlace donde se explica con un poco más de profundidad por si puede ser de interés:
https://programacionymas.com/blog/consultas-laravel-eficientes-usando-eloquent